# Xcode: Can't Build Downloaded Project because Compiler Cannot Find a Framework

Tags: cocoa, frameworks, xcodebuild

I'm new to this so please make allowances.

I'm trying to build [Audioslicer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/audioslicer/files/) which seems to need a framework called `IntervalSlider`.  The `IntervalSlider` build fails with:

```
 framework not found InterfaceBuilderKit.
```

However, the framework seems to be present under the `Frameworks` group with the necessary headers.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact build error output from Xcode's Build Results window.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this looked interesting so I downloaded the source. I built it and got an entire slew of build errors.

It looks like

1. According to source forge, this project hasn't been update since 2006-12-04 and the default SDK is still set to 10.4.
2. This project uses a bunch of uncompiled libraries/frameworks which need to be compiled to work. Some of them may no longer compile now nearly 4 years later and on new hardware/OS.
3. This is a complex project which mixes, Objective-C, vanilla C and C++, so it's not the kind of project a novice can reasonably expect to get working. (I'm not even sure I could get it updated.)

In short, this looked like a good idea in its day but the project has gone silent, stale and out of date. You'll need to find an alternative unless you want to spend weeks or months (1) learning how to build such a complex project and (2) tracking down all the updated versions of libraries (assuming they exist.)

I advise looking for another solution. Too bad because this looked like a really neat idea.  Such is the fate of a most FOSS. It takes too much drudgery coding to keep something like this up to date. All the fun in coding comes from the creation. Maintenance coding is about as fun as washing the dishes. Few are will to undertake such a chore year-in-year-out without pay.

In the future, always check the last project update date. If its more than a year or the before the last major OS rev, expect problems.

Comment: You're a better man than I. I saw it was a cvs repo and gave up ;-)

Comment: MANY THANKS. I APPRECIATE THE HELP. I WAS AFRAID THIS WAS THE CASE. I WILL TAKE YOUR ADVICE AND CONTINUE LOOKING.